# Attempting to iterate through exisitng items, checking if each exists in list provided, removing if it does not

Tags: c#, loops, windows-phone-8

I am attempting to iterate through existing sounds (isolatedGroup) and checking if each still exists in the list provided by assetsGroup. If not, I want it removed.  I am getting 3 errors when I add the portion of code for iterating.

Errors:

```
Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'

Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type SaveSoundGroup' 

.SaveSoundGroup' does not contain a definition for 'RemoveAt' and no extension method    'RemoveAt' accepting a first argument of type .SaveSoundGroup' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The errors occur at

```
for (int i = 0; i < isolatedGroup.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!assetsGroup.Contains(isolatedGroup[i]))
            {
                isolatedGroup.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
```

Full code:

```
private SoundGroup LoadFromXml(string xmlName)
    {
        SaveSoundGroup isolatedGroup = new SaveSoundGroup();
        SaveSoundGroup assetsGroup;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveSoundGroup));

        using (Stream fileStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Xmls/" + xmlName, UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
        {
            assetsGroup = (SaveSoundGroup)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
        }

        if (IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().FileExists(xmlName))
        {
            using (Stream fileStream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().OpenFile(xmlName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                isolatedGroup = (SaveSoundGroup)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
            }

            foreach (var entry in assetsGroup.Items)
            {
                if (!isolatedGroup.Items.Contains(entry))
                {
                    isolatedGroup.Items.Add(entry);
                }

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < isolatedGroup.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!assetsGroup.Contains(isolatedGroup[i]))
                {
                    isolatedGroup.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isolatedGroup = assetsGroup;
        }

        return new SoundGroup(isolatedGroup);
    }
```

SavedSoundGroup code:

```
public class SoundGroup
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Group<SoundData>> Items { get; set; }

    public SoundGroup()
    {
        Items = new List<Group<SoundData>>();
    }

    public SoundGroup(SaveSoundGroup data)
    {
        this.Title = data.Title;
        this.Items = new List<Group<SoundData>>();

        foreach (var group in data.Items.GroupBy(item => item.Groups))
        {
            this.Items.Add(new Group<SoundData>(group.Key, group.ToList()));
        }
    }
}

public class SaveSoundGroup
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<SoundData> Items { get; set; }

    public SaveSoundGroup()
    {
        this.Title = string.Empty;
        this.Items = new List<SoundData>();
    }

    public SaveSoundGroup(SoundGroup data)
        : this()
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            this.Title = data.Title;
            this.Items = new List<SoundData>();

            foreach (var group in data.Items)
            {
                this.Items.AddRange(group);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample of XML:

```
 <SaveSoundGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Title>cellular os</Title>
 <Items>
 <SoundData>
  <Title>** Outro Lex Ring **</Title>
  <FilePath>https://*********/Outro_Lex_Ring.mp3</FilePath>
  <Groups>Animals</Groups>
  <SavePath>Outro Lex Ring.mp3</SavePath>
  <Status>NotDownloaded</Status>
  <DownloadProgress>0</DownloadProgress>
</SoundData>

    <SoundData>
        <Title>Blackberry 3Beeps</Title>
        <FilePath>https://*********/Blackberry_3Beeps.mp3</FilePath>
        <Groups>Blackberry</Groups>
        <SavePath>Blackberry_3Beeps.mp3</SavePath>
        <Status>NotDownloaded</Status>
        <DownloadProgress>0</DownloadProgress>
    </SoundData>
```

Comment: First error is because Count is a method, should be Count(). Your SaveSoundGroup does not include indexer methods so can not be accessed through [].

Comment: Is there any other way to Remove items from the isolatedGroup that no longer exist in the assetsGroup (xml) other than this iterations coding?  Something similar to the `foreach (var entry in assetsGroup.Items)...` ?

Comment: Your SaveSoundGroup will need to implement ICollection to get a RemoveAt method. You can use a linq query to delete by criteria

Comment: How difficult is it to implement ICollection into what I currently have?  I assume this would require a re-write of much of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < isolatedGroup.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!assetsGroup.Items.Contains(isolatedGroup.Items[i]))
                    {
                        isolatedGroup.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                        i--;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of sounds like you want to do a union operation. So consider to do `isolatedGroup.Union(assetsGroup)` to get an Enumerable of all soundGroups that are in both lists.

The error you get is probably due to a missing () after Count but that depends on how it is defined in SaveSoundGroup. Same goes for the other errors. It seems SaveSoundGroup should inherit from `ICollection` or `Collection` but is not defined that way. That's why a lot of stuff your are using does not work. So please consider to post the code of your SaveSoundGroup class.

**UPDATE**
Ok, after having your SaveSoundGroup class I would recommend to do it like this:

```
public class SoundGroup : List<Group<SoundData>>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public SoundGroup() {}

    public SoundGroup(SaveSoundGroup data) : base(data.GroupBy(item => item.Groups).Select(grp => new Group<SoundData>(grp.Key, grp.ToList())))
    {
        this.Title = data.Title;
    }
}
public class SaveSoundGroup : List<SoundData>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public SaveSoundGroup()
    {
        this.Title = string.Empty;
    }

    public SaveSoundGroup(SoundGroup data)
    : base()
    {
        this.Title = data.Title;
        foreach(var grp in data)
            this.AddRange(grp);
    }
}
```

Stuff like Count and LINQ should work now. So you can do what you want now with `isolatedGroup.Union(assetsGroup)` as I already wrote.

Comment: Thanks.  There is one error with the changes you suggested.   at base(data.Items ......   Error is:  '*.ViewModels.SaveSoundGroup' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'Tonality.ViewModels.SaveSoundGroup' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: forgot to remove Items property. fixed it

Comment: Great, thank you. One small issue. In the other code, this will have an error now when it looks for Items I add to the xml to add. So it will now have the same error regarding Items I mentioned previously. How should this one be modified:   `foreach (var entry in assetsGroup.Items)
                {
                    if (!isolatedGroup.Items.Contains(entry))
                    {
                        isolatedGroup.Items.Add(entry);
                    }`

Comment: Just remove **.Items** `foreach (var entry in assetsGroup) { if (!isolatedGroup.Contains(entry)) { isolatedGroup.Add(entry); }`

Comment: Thanks. I really do appreciate your help. Going to have to go back to the drawing board on this. Those errors go away but I think I need Items to be in the code, as its in my xml. I get an exception when attempting to launch the app now. Everything was fine until I wanted to put in the Iteration to Remove items that are no longer in the xml.